# MediaWiki: an imported template returns many errors

Tags: mediawiki

I've installed a mediawiki and imported an example page from Wikipedia. But the template is not shown properly. https://wordpress-251650-782015.cloudwaysapps.com/wiki/Cheeta

Any hint on what could be the cause?

Comment: Forget about it. Wikipedia templates are so intricated that it is almost impossible to import.

Comment: @IRA1777: :( but how do I manage it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely missing one or more required templates/Lua modules this template relies on. If you want to get all the required templates/modules you can get them via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export by inserting the template name and ticking the box saying Include templates, and then importing the file generated from that via http://wordpress-251650-782015.cloudwaysapps.com/wiki/Speciale:Importa. However in most cases, except if you desperately want the exact look and feel its easier to write your one template, because Wikipedia templates get enormously complex

Comment: Thanks, for me it would be enough to have the basic template working (i.e. cite template)

Comment: @Revious for citation specifically, I believe the English Wikipedia has a guide to setting up a basis version of their system somewhere, but I can't remember where of the top of my head.